# Cannot run load_model (keras) on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, keras

I'm facing an error when trying to load the model 'small_model.h5'
The code is as follow

```
small_model = load_model('small_model.h5')
```

The error message is as follows

```
AttributeError module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'global_variables'
```

I've tried to upgrade the tensorflow and keras on the board but it didn't help. Also, I've tried another way of reading the file by using

```
small_model = 'small_model.h5'
small_modl = h5py.File(small_model,'r')
```

and didn't help

Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/buriburisuri/SRGAN/issues/3

Comment: ... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054784/possible-compatibility-issue-with-keras-tensorflow-and-scikit-tf-global-variab?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa